# RegSetValueEx returns success, but registry values not updating in regedit

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I've read numerous posts, but none seem to apply to the issue I'm experiencing.

First off, I inherited the current registry values, hence I'm forced to use KEY_WOW64_32KEY.  (64-bit app writing to the 32-bit registry)

Here is what I'm experiencing, from my C++ code: If I set a registry value (with the code below) and then get the registry value (with the code below), it appears to work fine (my 'get' equals my 'set').

But when I open regedit (32-bit version) the value is not getting updated.  I even checked regedit (64-bit version) and the value is not even there (as expected).

Thank you to the first responder - I have incorporated those suggestions and posted a rewrite; and for the sake of debugging I put in some hard coded values (just before the call to RegSetValueEx).  These will be removed once I figure this out.

Note that all this code executes just fine and returns ERROR_SUCCESS.

So, just to reiterate my question: why is regedit not updating with the values used by my RegSetValueEx?

BTW - I played with RegFlushKey, but no difference.  Also, I am compiling with UNICODE.  What am I missing?

```
/************************************************************************************
************************************************************************************/
LRESULT PWRegistry::SetValue(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring& sSubKey, const std::wstring& sName, const std::wstring& sValue)
{
    //  Init locals
    HKEY hRegKey(nullptr);
    DWORD dwAccess(KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_32KEY);    //  Set in the 32-bit registry
    LRESULT result(ERROR_SUCCESS);
    DWORD dwSize = (DWORD)((sValue.length() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));

    //  Open the key
    result = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, sSubKey.c_str(), 0, dwAccess, &hRegKey);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //  Create it
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegCreateKey(hKey, sSubKey.c_str(), &hRegKey))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    //  Hardcode some values during debugging
    TCHAR tcName[] = L"APP_ABBR";
    TCHAR tcValue[] = L"TLM";
    dwSize = (DWORD)((lstrlen(tcValue) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)); // This equals 8

    //  Set the value
    result = RegSetValueEx(hRegKey, tcName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)tcValue, dwSize);

    if (hRegKey!= nullptr)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hRegKey);
    }

    return result;
}

/************************************************************************************
************************************************************************************/
LRESULT PWRegistry::GetValue(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpszSubKey, LPCTSTR lpszValueName, DWORD dwType, LPBYTE pData, DWORD dwDataSize)
{
    DWORD dwOptions(0);
    DWORD dwAccess(KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_32KEY);  //  Get from the 32-bit registry

    HKEY hRegKey(nullptr);
    LRESULT result = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpszSubKey, dwOptions, dwAccess, &hRegKey);

    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        result = RegQueryValueEx(hRegKey, lpszValueName, NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)pData, &dwDataSize);
    }

    if (hRegKey != NULL)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hRegKey);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are using Win32 structured exception handling (__try, __leave, __finally) as a glorified goto where C++ exception handling will do. The downsize of having a __finally block is that if an actual program crash occured, your program attempts to execute code in a bad state.  I highly recommend you avoid structured exception handling in favor of C++ exceptions and/or traditional if/else blocks to control program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing - but just in case someone else visits this space or is running into a similar issue - it came down to pilot error.

The passed sub key name (sSubKey) was '1-level' above where it was supposed to be.  Consequently, when I examined regedit, I didn't see them in the anticipated location - and then I finally noticed them 1-level above. Doh!

When I passed in the correct sSubKey, the above functions worked as expected.